# Deriving the number of students reading three newspapers based on information regarding readership of each

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

There are $3$ newspapers $A , B , C$ and $400$ students. $180$ students read $A$; $270$ read $B$; and $371$ read $C$. I want to figure out at least how many are there who read all three.

I tried with Venn diagrams but ended up having two many variables and too less information. May be I am not doing it right. How to do this?

Comment: How many students are there in total?

Comment: What is the relation with "elementary-set-theory"?

Comment: This is a problem of set theory.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388757/sport-venn-diagram?rq=1

Comment: I tried with venn diagrams but ended up having two many variables and too less information . May be i am not doing it right . Please help in a more clear way.

Comment: The total number of students is $400$?

Comment: @MattiP. I think so.

Comment: If we don't know the total number of students, the sum of the individual groups is $180+270+371=821$. This is way more than $400$, so there has to be some overlap between the groups....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asssume that we have a Venn diagram like below:

[image]

We will have

${\begin{cases}a_1+a_4+a_6+a_7=180\\a_2+a_4+a_5+a_7=270\\a_3+a_5+a_6+a_7=371\\a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7=400\end{cases}}$ and we need to find the minimum value of $a_7$.

We know that:

- At least zero students only read one newspaper $A$.
- At least zero students only read one newspaper $B$.
- At least zero students only read one newspaper $C$.

$\Rightarrow a_1+a_2+a_3\ge 0$.

We also have

$a_1+a_2+a_3\ge 0$

$\Rightarrow a_7-a_7+a_1+a_2+a_3\ge 0$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge -a_1-a_2-a_3+a_7$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge (a_1-2a_1)+(a_2-2a_2)+(a_3-2a_3)+(a_4+a_4-2a_4)+(a_5+a_5-2a_5)+(a_6+a_6-2a_6)+(a_7+a_7+a_7-2a_7)$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge a_1+a_4+a_6+a_7+a_2+a_4+a_5+a_7+a_3+a_5+a_6+a_7-2a_1-2a_2-2a_3-2a_4-2a_5-2a_6-2a_7$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge A+B+C-2(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7)$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge 180+270+371-2\times 400$

$\Rightarrow a_7\ge 21$

The equality holds if $a_1=a_2=a_3=0;a_4=29;a_5=220;a_6=130;a_7=21$.

So at least $21$ students read all three newspapers. This method can be generalized for most cases.

Comment: How did you introduce -2a7 in the 4th line after "We also have"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited, change "$a_7+a_7-2a_7\rightarrow a_7+a_7+a_7-2a_7$". I figured out the solution by setting up a table for smaller amount of students to predict at least how many students will read all three newspapers in terms of $A,B,C$, then reverse it to have my proof.

Answer (score 1):

Maximize the number of people who read $2$ newspapers in order to find the least amount of people who read all three newspapers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everyone reads at least one newspaper, the addition formula:
$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C) \Rightarrow\\
400=180+270+371-(P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C))+P(A\cap B\cap C).$$
To minimize $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, we must maximize the number inside brackets, for which we must minimize the number of people reading only $A$, $B$, $C$ (i.e. set them equal to $0$):
$$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)-421=\\
400+2P(A\cap B\cap C)-421 \Rightarrow \\
P(A\cap B\cap C)=21.$$